# ssh chaining with local key files - how is this supposed to work?

Tags: ssh

I'm trying to get ssh chaining to work via a `jump` server to a `target` server on an internal subnet, so I can get to the target server in one command. ssh'ing works if I get to the target server in two hops:

```
local$ ssh -i=jump_rsa ec2@jump
jump$ ssh -i=target_rsa centos@target
target$
```

**What I want to do is chain these ssh connections together in one command, only using ssh private keys on the local machine, as I understand this is the most secure solution (currently there is a private key on the jump server).**

However I've completely failed to chain these together in one command, and I've drawn a blank trying to debug the problem. A possible complication here is that the local server is Ubuntu, the jump server amazon linux, and the target server centos7; so I'm wondering if this something to do with it?

### Attempt 1 - via the command line

```
$ ssh -A -t -i jump_rsa ec2-user@18.134.xx.xx ssh -A -t -i target_rsa centos@10.0.0.214
Warning: Identity file target_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.214 port 22: No route to host
Connection to 18.134.xx.xx closed.
```

I've tried putting the key files everywhere, and changing permissions and it makes no difference. with -v

```
Warning: Identity file target_rsa not accessible: No such file or directory.
OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 10.0.0.214 [10.0.0.214] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 10.0.0.214 port 22: No route to host
ssh: connect to host 10.0.0.214 port 22: No route to host
Connection to 18.134.xx.xx closed.
```

Is what I'm trying to do even possible There are lots of examples, but none using two key files references as I'm trying to do.

### Attempt 2 - via the .ssh/config file and proxycommand

```
# .ssh/config
Host jump
  Hostname 18.134.xx.xx
  User ec2-user
  Port 22
  IdentityFile /home/path/to/jump_rsa
  
Host target
  Hostname 10.0.0.214
  User centos
  IdentityFile /home/path/to/target_rsa
  Port 22
  ProxyCommand ssh -q W %h:%p jump
```

The command `ssh jump` works ok, to get to the jump server, but `ssh target` fails as shown below:

```
$ ssh target -v
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/peter/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/peter/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for target
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -q W 10.0.0.214:22 jump
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/target_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/target_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

I think I'm missing something obvious here, but can't see what.

---

Update...

### Attempt 3 - via -J

Tried the -J option, this is a bit more helpful, and there are some intriguing errors in there. But still doesn't work.

```
$ ssh -J jump target -v
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/peter/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/peter/.ssh/config line 16: Applying options for target
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Setting implicit ProxyCommand from ProxyJump: ssh -v -W '[%h]:%p' jump
debug1: Executing proxy command: exec ssh -v -W '[10.0.0.214]:22' jump
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/target_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/target_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1, OpenSSL 1.1.1f  31 Mar 2020
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/peter/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/peter/.ssh/config line 10: Applying options for jump
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 18.134.xx.xx [18.134.xx.xx] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/jump_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/path/to/jump_rsa_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.4 pat OpenSSH_7.0*,OpenSSH_7.1*,OpenSSH_7.2*,OpenSSH_7.3*,OpenSSH_7.4*,OpenSSH_7.5*,OpenSSH_7.6*,OpenSSH_7.7* compat 0x04000002
debug1: Authenticating to 18.134.xx.xx:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:302ZU2HdNyCd7uk+oGiKxoXKe+7eIYRIFNEFzAt9UJU
debug1: Host '18.134.xx.xx' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/peter/.ssh/known_hosts:31
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug1: Will attempt key: /home/path/to/jump_rsa  explicit
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information
No Kerberos credentials available (default cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_1000)


debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/peter/path/to/jump_rsa
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to 18.134.xx.xx ([18.134.xx.xx]:22).
debug1: channel_connect_stdio_fwd 10.0.0.214:22
debug1: channel 0: new [stdio-forward]
debug1: getpeername failed: Bad file descriptor
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0
channel 0: open failed: connect failed: No route to host
stdio forwarding failed
kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
```

```
# .ssh/config
Host jump
  Hostname 18.134.xx.xx
  User ec2-user
  Port 22
  IdentityFile /home/path/to/jump_rsa
  
Host target
  Hostname 10.0.0.214
  User centos
  IdentityFile /home/path/to/target_rsa
  Port 22
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was as Ginnungagap suggested using the -J option. But the problem I was seeing (at least with Attempt 3) was due to the permissions on the target server being too loose. Once I set them (via a user_data bootstrap script that also installs the public key) everything worked OK.

Full solution:

1. Ensure any centos nodes have the following permissions set (no harm for other flavours of linux too)

```
chmod 700 ~/.ssh
chmod 600 ~/.ssh/*
```

2. Configure the ~/.ssh.config file on the local machine as shown below:

```
# Speed up ssh by disabling this, as N/A for AWS
Host *
  GSSAPIAuthentication no
  
Host jump
  Hostname 35.178.207.12
  # Amazon Linux = ec2-user, Ubuntu = ubuntu, CentOS = centos
  User ec2-user
  Port 22
  IdentityFile /path/to/bastion_rsa
  
Host target
  Hostname 10.0.0.145
  # Amazon Linux = ec2-user, Ubuntu = ubuntu, CentOS = centos
  User centos
  IdentityFile /path/to/target_rsa
  Port 22
```

3. Connect to the target server using the command: `ssh -J jump target`

Avoiding the need for any private keys to be installed on the jump server.

Answer (score 0):

OpenSSH's `ssh` has the `-J` switch or `ProxyJump` option just for that.

From `man ssh`:

> **-J** *destination*
>
> > Connect to the target host by first making a **ssh** connection to the jump host described by *destination* and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate destination from there. Multiple jump hops may be specified separated by comma characters. This is a shortcut to specify a **ProxyJump** configuration directive. Note that configuration directives supplied on the command-line generally apply to the destination host and not any specified jump hosts. Use *~/.ssh/config* to specify configuration for jump hosts.

Comment: Hi, I tried -J. Still didn't work. But got some more helpful error messages. See the updated post `Attempt 3`